# Question about a sentence construction (has/have)

Tags: construction

> 1. Who have we got in the next round?
> 2. Who have you arranged to meet later on?
> 3. Who have they coming over for dinner?

i know that after who we put has like this example

> who has the car?

but in those 3 sentences thay put have could you tell me why please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb matches the subject of each sentence:  1. We , 2. You, 3. They.

Example:

> Who **have we** got in the next round?   **We have** Bruce the Bruiser against Max the Mangler!

In the case where we don't know the subject, we assume it's a singular entity (*he*, *she*, or *it*, some proper name like *Michael*, *Francine*, or Bill the Cat, or some other named entity like *the President*, *the neighbor*, etc.).

> Who **is** making dinner tonight?  **Frank is** -- **he is** making stew.

Side note: You originally wrote "ye" which I changed to "you".  "Ye" is Old English and is no longer commonly used.

Comment: what about the second sentence (Who have you arranged to meet later on?)

what if i will meet just 1 person can i still use have ?

Comment: is it correct to say who has he invited for dinner today ?

Comment: @HussamHamdeh  Yes, as I said in the answer, the subject of the second sentence is **you**, not **who**.